# Getting longitudes & latitudes from Chinese GPS location codes

Tags: gps, china

I received a request about getting the longitudes & latitudes from Chinese GPS location codes, which I had no idea about, and they do not look like something convertible with those online GPS converters.

They usually come with 2 set of numbers with 7 digits each.
For example:

- 0554390,4168686 (limited info shows it is located in Shaanxi province)
- 0589535,3567923 (limited info shows it is located in Anhui province)

How can I do this?